# Output a readable model file and control the solver parameters in Or-Tools

Tags: or-tools, parameter

I am using Java to call the API of or-tools in IntelliJ IDEA to solve a mixed-integer programming problem. There are some modeling statements such as `ModelSolver solver = new ModelSolver("SCIP");` and `ModelBuilder model = new ModelBuilder();`.

Prior to solving, I want to output a readable model file with suffix lp or mps. I tried `model.exportToFile("mip.lp")` and `model.exportToFile("mip.mps")`, which can output files normally but in binary form. If I output the file with the suffix txt, it can be opened normally on a mac but with poor readability.

In addition, I also tried `model.exportToLpString(true);` and `model.exportToMpsString(true);` methods, but I could not find the output file in the project path. Is there any way to output a more readable model file to speed up debugging?

Additionally, I want to set parameters during the solving process, such as `solver.setSolverSpecificParameters("limits/gap=0.01");`. Are there any other optional parameters for this input? I could not find the official manual for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelBuilder.exportToMpsString()` returns a string as the name suggests.

See the [doc](https://or-tools.github.io/docs/javadoc/com/google/ortools/modelbuilder/ModelBuilder.html#exportToMpsString-boolean-).

Parameters must be parsable by the solver. In your example, refer to the scip manual.

Comment: Great, thanks, it works.